# Adguard Home doesn't return local IP for domain when rewriting, but returns external IP

Tags: domain-name-system

I have three domains i want to have mapped:

1. r2.x --> 192.168.165.2
2. d2.x --> 135.181.103.62
3. test.x --> 10.1.2.3

I have added these to Adguard Home DNS rewrite. I have tested this with `dig` on another machine:

Dig for r2.x

> ❯ dig r2.x
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> r2.x
> ;; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54513
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;r2.x.                          IN      A
>
> ;; Query time: 10 msec
> ;; SERVER: 172.22.160.1#53(172.22.160.1)
> ;; WHEN: Wed Jun 23 08:56:00 CEST 2021
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 22

Dig for d2.x

> ❯ dig d2.x
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> d2.x
> ;; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27472
> ;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
> ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;d2.x.                          IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> d2.x.                   0       IN      A       135.181.103.62
>
> ;; Query time: 10 msec
> ;; SERVER: 172.22.160.1#53(172.22.160.1)
> ;; WHEN: Wed Jun 23 09:08:11 CEST 2021
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42

Dig for test.x

> ❯ dig test.x
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> test.x
> ;; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 1501
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
> ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;test.x.                                IN      A
>
> ;; Query time: 50 msec
> ;; SERVER: 172.22.160.1#53(172.22.160.1)
> ;; WHEN: Wed Jun 23 09:08:58 CEST 2021
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35

I can't figure out why Adguard Home doesn't want to resolve domains when the A record is a local IP. The strange thing is that the query log for `test.x` does in fact show a response with IP

[image: Adguard home query log for test.x]

Still `dig` doesn't show me anything. It is the same with `nslookup`:

> ➜  nslookup test.x
> Server:  amplifi.lan
> Address:  192.168.165.1
>
> *** amplifi.lan can't find test.x: Non-existent domain

But for d2.x `nslookup` resolves just fine

> ➜  nslookup d2.x
> Server:  amplifi.lan
> Address:  192.168.165.1
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:    d2.x
> Address:  135.181.103.62

There is nothing standing out in my upstream:

[image: AdGuard Home upstream settings]

I run version v0.106.3 of AdGuard Home on a raspberry pi.

I am not a network admin, nor am i a DNS wizard.

Can anyone here tell me why `dig` only gets shown external IPs, but not local IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by manually adding the AdGuard Home as a alternate DNS
[image: Alternate DNS]

The strange thing is still:

1. my router is still requesting the test.x on the AdGuard Home
2. AdGuard Home still answers with "test.x has this IP"
3. dig is returning the IP, but is now using the alternate DNS

This i think i strange, because my router is resolving the IP correctly, I can see the resolve in the query log (AdGuard is saying "here is the IP for test.x).

I am sure there is a good explanation. I would still like to have one, but for now, it is resoling everything correctly, and i like that.